# Reading XML from relative path - java.io.FileNotFoundException:(The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, xml, string, file, bufferedreader

I have the following method that should check if two XML documents are matching:

```
@Test
public void currentXMLShouldMatchXMLSpecification() throws Exception {

    String xml1 = convertXMLToString("/module/docs/document1.xml");
    String xml2 = convertXMLToString("/module/docs/document2.xml");

    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); // ignore whitespace differences

    assertXMLEquals(xml1, xml2); 
}
```

**Convert XML to String method:**

```
   public static String convertXMLToString(String filePath) throws IOException {

        //filename is filepath string
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append(line.trim());
        }

        return  line;
    }
```

**Assert XML Equals Method:**

```
   public static void assertXMLEquals(String expectedXML, String actualXML) throws Exception {
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

        DetailedDiff diff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXML, actualXML));

        List<?> allDifferences = diff.getAllDifferences();
        Assert.assertEquals("Differences found: " + diff.toString(), 0, allDifferences.size());
    }
```

**Error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:(The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
```

Do I need to move my XML document to be under the Resources folder? Or is this a code mistake I am making?

Please note that the test class containing this test is not in the same module as the document I am trying to read.

Comment: Please put the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For java unit tests such as this, my recommendations for test files are:

1. Test resources go under `src/test/resources`, and then in a folder to match the package of the test class.
2. Use `IOUtils.toString(InputStream)` from `commons-io` to read in the file.
3. Use `Class.getResourcesAsStream(String)` to reference the file itself.

Thus for `com.my.package.MyTest`, I would save the XML file as `src/test/resources/com/my/package/test_document1.xml`, and the code might look like:

```
try(InputStream in = MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("test_document1.xml")) {
    return IOUtils.toString(in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should move any non-java files to the resources folder. And if you put them under `module/docs/` folder, then you should also change your code to something like this:

```
String xml1 = convertXMLToString("module/docs/document1.xml");
String xml2 = convertXMLToString("module/docs/document2.xml");
```

All the files under `resources` folder would be automatically copied to your classpath root folder so the `module/` folder would be relative to the root of your classpath.

**EDIT:**
When you're doing tests, your test folder has its own `resources` folder and so files should be accessible there. If you want to dynamically copy your files there, then you can do it in one of the following ways:

1. Copy files to the test output folder in the `@Before` method of your test. The method annotated with `@Before` in your test, runs before any tests in your unit test class.
2. Use your build script (maven, gradle, etc.) to add an extra step to be run before your tests to do this

I recommend to use the second approach because it's more robust and configurable.

Comment: Is there a way that I can dynamically copy the file into my resources folder when the test is ran, I ask as for now I need to keep the actual file in same location, i.e. not in the resources folder?

Comment: Currently,what is the full path to your xml files?

Comment: @java123999 I updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: can you please show an example of the @before method?

Comment: Add a method like this to your test class
`@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        // copy files from source to destination
    }`